# Unrecognized datatype in Sequelize Model

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create an attribute called "provider" in my postgresql model and make its data type an Object (see code below). However, I am getting the error `Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "segment.provider"`.

I'm assuming this error is happening because I haven't specified what the data type of the "provider" attribute actually is (ie: `type: DataTypes.OBJECT`). To my knowledge, there's nothing in the Sequelize docs that demonstrates this ask of mine. Any and all help would be most appreciated. Thanks!

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Segment = sequelize.define(
    'segment',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      provider: {
        providerName: DataTypes.STRING,
        externalId: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        privacyPolicy: DataTypes.STRING
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'segment'
    }
  );

  return Segment;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every field defined on a model(Table) is mapped into a column on the database.
That is what `sequelize` basically does.

Now, is there a field on a `PostgreSQL` database which is an object?

For what you are trying to do, you just need to use associations between tables.
Create a new model (Table) called `provider`:

And add the associations as follows in the example:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Provider = sequelize.define(
    'provider',
    {
      id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
      },
      name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      email: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      privacyPolicy: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'provider'
    }
  );

  // Apply the accosiation:
  Provider.hasMany /* or has one */ (Segment, {foreignKey: 'provider_id'});
  return Provider;
}
```

And in your `Segment` model add a foreign key and a reference to `Provider`

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Segment = sequelize.define(
    'segment',
    {
      id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
      },
      provider_id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          references: {
              model: 'provider',
              key: 'id
          }
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'segment'
    }
  );

  // Apply the accosiation:
  Segment.belongsTo(Provider, {foreignKey: 'id'}); 
  return Segment;
}
```